# How to build a GUI interface for C++ and OpenCV ( Dnn, yolov3) project (using Visual Studio )

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-c++, clr, yolo

I am using a C++ car counting project ( using OpenCV and YoloV3 ) , and it runs perfectly well in a native C++ project but I wanted to add a window to the project (in which i will then display a video, forms, etc..) I searched how to implement a GUI for C++ and found about CLR . So I tried to integrate my C++ project files into a new CLR project and when i run it I have this error:
[image]

Is there another way to create a GUI? If not, can anyone help me solve that error? ( Note that I am new to using C++ )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your options are limited due to the C++ ecosystem.

The easiest to learn probably QT.

If you wanted to be a little more hardcore you could use imgui with OpenGL but that is likely overkill.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Does QT work well with OpenCV ?

Comment: @AntsaR You did not at me so I never say this, I am sorry. If you don;t use the @ the user won;t be notified even if you comment under the answer.

In general they are independent of each other, they work as well as any 2 unrelated libraries that you would glue together in say, python.